# How can I get an algebraic equation of a median curved line from ggplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, equation, median

I have made a code that extracts multiple flood events (colored lines), clusters them (3 clusters) and plots them together in one picture. Additionally, I used the ggplot stat.summary command to visually find a median line (black) that represents a shape of the each group so I can compare them. This is the code that I used to get this plot:

```
df %>% ggplot(aes(
  x = flowDayShifted,
  y = flowScaled,
  group = interaction(clusterFourier, as.factor(peak_number)),
  colour = as.factor(year)
)) + geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~ clusterFourier,  ncol = 3) +
  stat_summary(
    fun.y = "median",
    aes(group = clusterFourier),
    color = "black",
    geom = "line",
    size = 1.2
  )
```

[image]

Is there a possibility to get the algebraic equation of the each median line from the ggplot somehow? I do not know what rank is the line nor anything about it, I only see it visually.

Thank you!

I tried sth along these lines but did not get an actual equation. I do know the equation can be quite a mess but that does not matter if it is the correct representation.

```
# Extract information about the median line
median_layer <- ggplot_build(gg)$data[[length(ggplot_build(gg)$data)]]
# Fit a model to the median line data
median_model <- loess(y ~ x, data = median_layer, span = 0.75)  # You can adjust span as needed
# Print the summary of the fitted model
summary(median_model)
```

Comment: `stat_summary` is literally just calculating the median value of `flowScaled` at each value of `flowDayShifted` within each `clusterFourier`. There is no algebreic formula. It is just a bunch of data points joined by a line. If you want the data points, you can get them using `dplyr::sumarise(df, medianflow = median(flowScaled), .by = c(clusterFourier, flowDayShifted))`

Comment: Thank you very much. This was helpfull aswell. However, my final product should be the formula of the line for further analyses. Do you maybe have an idea how to get it? Thank you

Comment: But that's my point Martina - there _is_ no formula for the line. The line is actually several short line segments connecting arbitrary points. Its shortest algebraic description is just the coordinates of the points, which you can get as I described above.